# Convert .R files to .txt files en masse

Tags: r, rstudio, file-conversion

I have about 56 .R files that I need to convert to .txt format--not R objects or data frames but the .R files themselves I need to convert to a text format.

Is there a package or method to do this for many files, or is doing it one by one the only option?

Comment: A `.R` file is a text file. What are you trying to do? Do you just want to change the extension (from `.R` to `.txt`)?

Answer (score 1):

Base R approach:

```
# get list of .R files in current directory
my_r_files <- list.files(pattern = "*\\.R$")

# specify new name for each file
new_file_names <- sub(pattern="\\.R$", replacement=".txt", x=my_r_files)

# rename files
file.rename(from = my_r_files, to = new_file_names)
```

Comment: maybe `name_without_extension=sub(my_r_files,"\\.R$",".txt"); file.rename(my_r_files,name_without_extension)` ? you don't need the loop (both `sub` and `file.rename` are vectorized)

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker - I've updated my answer to remove the loop.

Comment: But you didn't fix the first pattern.